# Why nm hides .rela.eh_frame and .rela.text in .o files?

Tags: c, elf, relocation, nm

I'm trying to recreate the behaviour of the command `nm` in C, and although I was successful getting the names of the symbols and sections, I find out that some extra names appear in my version.

`$> ./my_nm -a obj.o`

```
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 n .comment
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 r .eh_frame
0000000000000000 n .note.GNU-stack
0000000000000000 r .note.gnu.property
0000000000000000 d .rela.eh_frame
0000000000000000 d .rela.text
0000000000000000 t .text
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T elf64_syms
0000000000000000 a elf64_syms.c
                 U malloc
```

`$> nm -a obj.o`

```
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 n .comment
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 r .eh_frame
0000000000000000 n .note.GNU-stack
0000000000000000 r .note.gnu.property
0000000000000000 t .text
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T elf64_syms
0000000000000000 a elf64_syms.c
                 U malloc
```

I did some research about them and found that they are some sort of a reference to a section or symbol. I wonder if there is anything special about them. If so, how can I differentiate between them and other `.rela...`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I find out that some extra names appear in my version.

The Linux `nm` version uses `libbfd`, which maps different object file formats into its own *internal* data model, and then `nm` prints that internal representation.

`libbfd` predates `ELF` by at least 2 decades, and its internal model is *inadequate* for representing complexities of the `ELF` format (things get lost in translation).

For this reason, one generally *shouldn't* use `nm`, `objdump` and other `libbfd`-based tools to examine `ELF` files (use `readelf` instead, which shows things *as they are* without translation losses).

So, you've done *nothing wrong* and your version of `nm` is *better*.